# run a function from a button in a frame

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm just starting with python 3, I've made 3 scripts which do what I want them to do and now I'm trying to include them in a very basic GUI that I made with tinker.

I've joined my 3 scripts into a single file and made a function of each of them

Basically I'd like to run this or that function when I click on a button in the frame.

The problem is that of course I d'ont know how to do it, can someone point me in the right direction ?

Thanks for the help.

```
from tkinter import *
from datetime import *
import time
def c60duree(delta):
    (h, r) = divmod(delta.seconds, 3600)
    (m, s) = divmod(r, 60)
    return "%s%02d:%02d:%02d" % (
        "%d jour(s) " % delta.days if delta.days > 0 else "",
        h,
        m,
        s,
    )
def code60():
    saisie=0
    c60=[[],[]]
    while saisie != "X":
        c60d=datetime.now()
        print ("Code 60 activé à ", c60d.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        saisie=input("Tapez entree pour la fin du code 60, X pour sortir   : ")
        c60f=datetime.now()
        print("Debut ", c60d.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        print("Fin   ", c60f.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        c60x=c60f-c60d
        print("Duree ", c60duree(c60x))
        print("-------------")
        c60[0].append(c60d)
        c60[1].append(c60f)
#del(c60[0],[-1])
#del(c60[1],[-1])
#return

def relais():
    rel=[[],[],[],[],[]]
    print("Relais pilote demarré ")
    relh=datetime.now()
    relv=input("Quelle voiture ? ")
    relp=input("Quel pilote repart ? ")
    rele=input("Quantité d'essence ? ")
    input("Tapez entrée à la sortie des stands ")
    rels=datetime.now()
    rel[0].append(relh), rel[1].append(relv), rel[2].append(relp), rel[3].append(rele), rel[4].append(rels)
    print("Dureé ", rels-relh)
    print(*rel)

def essence():
    ess=[[],[],[],[]]
    print("Ravitaillement essence demarré ")
    essh=datetime.now()
    essv=input("Quelle voiture ? ")
    essp=input("Quel pilote ? ")
    essq=input("Combien de litres ? ")
    ess[0].append(essh), ess[1].append(essv), ess[2].append(essp), ess[3].append(essq)
    print(*ess)

fenetre = Tk()

fenetre['bg']='grey'

# frame 1
Frame1 = Frame(fenetre, bg="yellow", borderwidth=1, relief=GROOVE)
Frame1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

# frame 2
Frame2 = Frame(fenetre, bg="green", borderwidth=1, relief=GROOVE)
Frame2.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

# frame 3
Frame3 = Frame(fenetre, bg="red", borderwidth=1, relief=GROOVE)
Frame3.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

# Ajout de labels
Label(Frame1, text="Essence").pack(padx=300, pady=100)
Label(Frame2, text="Relais").pack(padx=300, pady=100)
Label(Frame3, text="C60").pack(padx=300, pady=100)
```

Comment: Small note: the `input()` function corresponds to [Entry](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/widgets.html#entry) in tkinter.

Comment: ok, first of I just come from a question that had a problem with imports, the main issue was that they imported using wildcard (`*`, all) which made some errors, so what I suggest is: unless You know the library/module very well (either just know it or You made it Yourself and basically You know every single method and class in there), You should import only what You need (`from module import need_this, This, also_this`) or import the module (`import module`), this will avoid name clashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to continue using Labels, you can bind a function to them like this:

```
# Ajout de labels
label1 = Label(Frame1, text="Essence")
label1.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: essence())
label1.pack(padx=300, pady=100)
label2 = Label(Frame2, text="Relais")
label2.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: relais())
label2.pack(padx=300, pady=100)
label3 = Label(Frame3, text="C60")
label3.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: code60())
label3.pack(padx=300, pady=100)
```

I've had to give the labels each a name so I could add the binding. The `bind` method takes a key and a function. The key I've given is `Button-1`, which is the left mouse button. Therefore when you click on the label the function is run. When you bind a function, and extra argument called `event` is added. For this example we don't need event, so I've used `lambda event:` to essentially ignore it and call the function like normal.
Another way you could do this is with buttons:

```
# Ajout de labels
Button(Frame1, text="Essence", command = essence).pack(padx=300, pady=100)
Button(Frame2, text="Relais", command = relais).pack(padx=300, pady=100)
Button(Frame3, text="C60", command = code60).pack(padx=300, pady=100)
```

This is a lot more straightforward but looks different to a Label.
**EDIT**
To make the text appear in the GUI, you could do something like this:

```
def essenceResult(ess, ent1, ent2, ent3):
    essh=datetime.now()
    essv = ent1.get()
    essp = ent2.get()
    essq = ent3.get()
    ess[0].append(essh), ess[1].append(essv), ess[2].append(essp), ess[3].append(essq)
    resultLabel = Label(Frame4, text = str(ess))
    resultLabel.grid(row = 5, column = 0, columnspan = 2)

def essence():
    print("yr")
    Frame4.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    ess=[[],[],[],[]]
    Label1 = Label(Frame4, text = "Ravitaillement essence demarré ")
    Label1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2)
    essvLabel = Label(Frame4, text = "Quelle voiture ? ")
    essvEntry = Entry(Frame4)
    essvLabel.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    essvEntry.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
    esspLabel = Label(Frame4, text = "Quel pilote ? ")
    esspEntry = Entry(Frame4)
    esspLabel.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
    esspEntry.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
    essqLabel = Label(Frame4, text = "Combien de litres ? ")
    essqEntry = Entry(Frame4)
    essqLabel.grid(row = 3, column = 0)
    essqEntry.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
    submitButton = Button(Frame4, text = "Submit", command = lambda: essenceResult(ess, essvEntry, esspEntry, essqEntry))
    submitButton.grid(row = 4, column = 0, columnspan = 2)
fenetre = Tk()

fenetre['bg']='grey'

# frame 1
Frame1 = Frame(fenetre, bg="yellow", borderwidth=1, relief=GROOVE)
Frame1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx=5, pady=5)

# frame 2
Frame2 = Frame(fenetre, bg="green", borderwidth=1, relief=GROOVE)
Frame2.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx=5, pady=5)

# frame 3
Frame3 = Frame(fenetre, bg="red", borderwidth=1, relief=GROOVE)
Frame3.grid(row = 0, column = 2, padx=5, pady=5)

Frame4 = Frame(fenetre)
```

`Frame4` is used to show the things for essence, but is not displayed until the user presses the button. The inputs have been replaced with a label for the question and an entry for the user to put their answer. Then when they press submit, the `essenceResult` function adds a label with what the print function used to show.

Comment: You can also pass in `relief="flat"` when creating a button. That makes the button look like a label when it isn't pressed.

Comment: @TheLizzard Yes, but it still has things like the button press animation that they may not want.

Comment: Hello,
Thanks for the help, there's an error with the "command", I just modified the 3 last lines with your code and I get this error on launch :
File "D:\Bureautique\Python\Scripts\interface.py", line 73, in <module>
    Label(Frame1, text="Essence", command = essence).pack(padx=300, pady=100)
  File "D:\Bureautique\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3148, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "D:\Bureautique\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2572, in __init__
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-command"

Comment: You can only use command if you change Label to Button

Comment: Otherwise you have to use the first method

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
With button it runs smoothly, perfect.
No is there a way to make the queries appear in the frame instead of in the IDLE program ?
Or ideally when "essence" is activated I could make a bigger "essence" frame and then run the prompts from within the frame ?
Finally when this runs as it should I will need to display results in the bottom of the "essence" frame with a spreadsheet-like grid.
Once again thanks for the help
JC

Comment: @Jean-CharlesHuillier I've edited the question to show you how you could do this. You could then do something similar for the other options.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's much better, I'll adjust this to the other frames.
Additional questions :)
How do i change the focus to the next question when I hit enter (if possible) ? I'd like the focus to be i the first window (quelle voiture) and then move on to the next question when I hit enter.
Can I make a spreadsheet-like grid which will display the last x answers ? I still have plenty of room to use and the users would love to have for example the last 10 refuel infos, which car, which driver, how many liters and at what time.
Once again thanks a lot for the help

Comment: You can use `something.focus()` to give focus to an widget (where `something` is a frame or entry, for example). To move on to the next question with enter, use `root.bind_all("<Return>", function)` do something when the user presses enter. You can make a spreadsheet grid with a for loop and some Entry widgets. Also, if the original answer helped you, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: I've managed the focus, for some reason you have to give the focus after the entry has been done
I can't get the root.bind to work, i've tried as follows and it just displays the first line and enter or tab does nothing, I'll try to find a way by myself and if I don't find it I'll ask you again :)

Here's the code as it stands now
    essvLabel = Label(Frame4, text = "Quelle voiture ? ")
    essvEntry = Entry(Frame4)
    essvLabel.grid(row = 1, column = 0
    essvEntry.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
    essvEntry.focus()
    root.bind_all(<"Return">, function)

Comment: Sorry, in your case `root` should be `fenetre`

Comment: Hello again (sorry ha ha).
fenetre.bind_all("<Return>", function) does not work, nor does'root.bind_all("<Return>", fenetre)
I've added a 5th data to be entered, namely the "start" time and I get this error
'esse = ent0.get()
AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'get''
Here's my reasoning, I created a ess_e=datetime.now() in the main function and I've created a ess_s=datetime.now() in the result display fucntion.
I've added a fifth place in the main ess=[[],[],[],[],[]] line which I've placed at the start of the script not to empty it each time I launch it

Comment: Then I've modified the result function as follows
def essenceResult(ess, ent0, ent1, ent2, ent3):
    ess_e = ent0.get()
    essv = ent1.get()
    essp = ent2.get()
    essq = ent3.get()
    ess_s = datetime.now()
    ess[0].append(ess_e), ess[1].append(essv), ess[2].append(essp), ess[3].append(essq), ess [4].append(ess_s)
    resultLabel = Label(Frame4, text = str(*ess))
    resultLabel.grid(row = 5, column = 0, columnspan = 2)

And I get the error so it seems I cannot transfer datetime type variables from the main function to the 2nd one, correct ?

Comment: I think it's better if you ask this as a new question so I can see the code you now have. That will make it easier to answer for me.